# PHPMailer stopped working. Postfix SSL alert number 45

Tags: ssl, postfix

PHPMailer worked fine until June 1st 2020. The SSL certificate for the site sending the email is valid from June 1st 2019 to June 1st 2021 and is accepted fine in the browser, but postfix suddenly has a TLS problem. I have access to both the email server and the web server attempting to send the email and they are running on the same network. I get the following messages when the site attempts to send the email.

```
log/maillog on the email server:
Jun  9 12:26:39 12-34-56-78 postfix/submission/smtpd[3299]: connect from unknown[12.34.56.80]
Jun  9 12:26:39 12-34-56-78 postfix/submission/smtpd[3299]: SSL_accept error from unknown[12.34.56.80]: 0
Jun  9 12:26:39 12-34-56-78 postfix/submission/smtpd[3299]: warning: TLS library problem: 3299:error:14094415:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 45:
Jun  9 12:26:39 12-34-56-78 postfix/submission/smtpd[3299]: lost connection after STARTTLS from unknown[12.34.56.80]
Jun  9 12:26:39 12-34-56-78 postfix/submission/smtpd[3299]: disconnect from unknown[12.34.56.80]
```

I checked that none of the configuration files have changed for either postfix or PHPMailer. They're still dated as last modified in 2019.

I don't want to disable 'verify peer' because it really ought to verify the peer. I just can't tell why it stopped working when the certificate hasn't changed, but I'm sure the dates are more than coincidental. How do I fix this and how do I prevent this in the first place?

** EDIT **

In my case the problem was that the CA bundle was expired, even though the certificate was valid. I think they have to be together in the same file for postfix config.

I completely misunderstood which side has issue with which. In this case the client had issue with the email server.

To fix:

1. Check postfix/main.cf (or whatever your file is named)
2. Look for the line specifying `smtpd_tls_cert_file`
3. Replace that file with the current cert (including the CA bundle)

EDIT:

I had a cert issued by the folling people, whose root CA bundle expired
https://www.ssls.com/knowledgebase/sectigo-root-certificate-expiring-may-30-2020/

Comment: *"The SSL certificate for the site sending the email is valid from June 1st 2019 to June 1st 2021 and is accepted fine in the browser, but postfix suddenly has a TLS problem."* - this statement makes no sense for me. The browser is accessing a HTTP server while postfix is accessing a SMTP server. These are different servers with different configuration  - and probably different certificates. It is likely that you've replaced the certificate for the web server but not for the mail server.

Comment: The webserver is sending an email using PHPMailer through smtp. If I understand the message right, postfix does not accept that the webserver is who it says it is. For clarification, dovecot is the smtp running on the postfix server, but it's not where the error was thrown, so I didn't think it was relevant.

Comment: *"postfix does not accept that the webserver is who it says it is"* - No, PHPMailer does not accept the certificate provided by Postfix. *"dovecot is the smtp running on the postfix server"* - dovecot is a IMAP/POP3 server and not a SMTP server. The SMTP server is Postfix. They are often used together though.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> ...postfix ... TLS library problem: ... ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert certificate expired ...
> ```

This message means that Postfix received (`ssl_read_bytes`) a TLS alert from the client (i.e. PHPMailer) that it will not accept the certificate provided by Postfix since this certificate is expired. This suggests that you maybe changed the certificate for the web server but that you kept the expired certificate for Postfix.

Comment: That is exactly the case for me, however putting the new certificates into main.cf and restarting postfix did not solve the issue...what else to do?

Comment: @br4nnigan: In this case your problem might be a different one. Please ask a new question with full details then.